# object coming out to be undefined using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jsx, use-effect

My location is coming out to be undefined, how can I solve this problem? If I console.log(location) after calling function getGeo, I get the lat and long, but in the fetch request they are coming out to be undefined, why is this? What would be a better way to write this code?

```
function Body(props) {
  const location = {};

  function getGeo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      location.long = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getGeo();

    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.lat}&lon=${location.long}&units=metric&appid=key`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: most likely because you dont have an api key, i removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a react state to track the value for location, so the component rerenders when the values are ready

```
   function Body(props) {
      const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
      
      function getGeo() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          setLocation({
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            long: position.coords.longitude,
          });
        });
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getGeo();
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        // early return when values are not ready
        if (location.lat === undefined || location.lang === undefined) return;
        
        fetch(
          `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location.lat}&lon=${location.long}&units=metric&appid=key`
        )
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          });
      }, [location.lat, location.long]);
```

Comment: I guess its getting caught up on the if statement for some reason, i dropped a console log in there and it's returning it.

Comment: @Jayg713 check the values before the `if`, probably lat or lang have a 0, since it's a falsy value it's entering the `if`. I'll update it to check for undefined instead

Comment: notices that second useEffect should run at least twice, because getGeo runs in the first render and then when it updates the state the second useEffect runs a second time

Comment: yes, 2nd useEffect is running twice. I combined the useEffects into one and passed the location dependency, still works the same way and no repeating cases

Comment: Do you mind going into a little more detail on what exactly the if statement is doing, so I can understand better? What do you mean by early return? What happens?

Comment: @Jayg713 it's a pattern https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8, in your case it is not worth to make a call to the api when `lat` or `lang` are `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This entire issue is about **variable scope**, let's look more closely:

```js
function Body(props) {
  /**
   * "location" is defined as empty object within entire scope
   * therefore "location.lat" and "location.long" are "undefined" in this scope
   * console.log(location.lat, location.long) -> undefined, undefined
   */
  const location = {};

  function getGeo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      // Within this scope, 
      // "location.lat" and "location.long" are defined (have values)
      location.lat = position.coords.latitude;
      location.long = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }

  // despite giving values to "location.lat" and "location.long", 
  // they are still "undefined"
  console.log(location.lat, location.long) // -> undefined, undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    getGeo();
    // Even within here, 
    // "location.lat"and "location.long" are "undefined" in this scope
  }, []);
```

**Solution**

- Using `React.useRef` to keep a reference to your variables

```js
import React from 'react';

function Body(props) {
  // reference your variables
  let lat = React.useRef('');
  let long = React.useRef('');

  function getGeo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      lat.current = position.coords.latitude;
      long.current = position.coords.longitude;
    });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // We call getGeo() to run first;
    // If it's successful, we now have values for "lat" and "long"
    getGeo();
    
    // We only do a fetch if "lat" and "long" have values
    // We use the key (current) to extract/check those values
    if (lat.current && long.current) {
       // Do a fetch
    }
  }, [lat, long]);
};
```

Comment: Awesome, just Curious is there any difference between useRef and React.useRef or React.useEffect and just useEffect? Is that a way to use it instead of importing it?

Comment: No difference, that's another way to use them (and never have to worry about importing each of those independently). Pretty cool, right?

Comment: Yes I never knew that!